# Modify Outlook "now alignment"

Tags: calendar, gui, time, microsoft-outlook-2019

is there a way to change MS Outlook's "planning view" to not put the blue now marker on the center of the screen when I navigate from another date to today?

[… I am unable to upload fotos …]